# Migrate java non-spring web application to pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: java, jdbc, migration, jndi, cloud-foundry

A Java Servlet-jsp app running on on-premise hardware is to be migrated to pivotal cloud PaaS.

Currently, the app takes DB credentials from server.xml of Tomcat and the resource is added in the context.xml.

This is the context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/db"
 global="jdbc/db"
 auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

This is server.xml

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/db" 
  global="jdbc/db" 
  auth="Container" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
  url="jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/db" 
  username="..." 
  password="..."      
  maxActive="100" 
  maxIdle="20" 
  minIdle="5" 
  maxWait="10000"/>
```

How can I pass the Credentials to the server? Is there any standard way to pass DB credentials for PaaS applications?

Comment: You can store credentials to Environment variables instead of passing to server. App can fetch the credentials from Environment variables.

Comment: but the credentials may have fields like host name, uname, password. can all be added as JSON? or app.yaml as suggested below can be used?

Comment: Also, I have mentioned already that it is a non-spring app

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring Boot application will be packaged as an executable JAR.  It'll have an application.yml file inside it that contains your database connection credentials.

You can also configure your data source as a Pivotal Cloud Foundry service. That way the credentials are added to the cloud.  Your app simply refers to them.

Comment: You mean, as environment variable?

Comment: No.  A file is not an environment variable.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: env:
    DB_ENV: "VALUE" , can this way in the manifest.yml, credentials be supplied? or need app.yaml ?

Comment: I know what an environment variable is.  You need more than one to configure a connection pool.  You should read about how to set up a connection pool in PCF.

Comment: I got your point @duffymo, I am exploring ways to do that. What I meant was, can credentials in the form of JSON be supplied as value? app.yaml will be a file addition for which, we may have to take permission from client.

Comment: You add them as .yml; please read the links.  Permission from client?  This is how PCF is done.  There's no choice here.